# Преобразовать секунды в MM:SS

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!
Как на php можно написать преобразование секунд в формат MM:SS (например есть 70 секунд, преобразуем в 1:10) без формул, т.е. как можно минимум кода

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Работу со временем и датами в PHP в основном выполняет функция `date`.

```
<?php

$time = 70;
echo date('i:s',$time);
?>
```

Comment: а допустим если очень много секунд? минуты только до 59 вроде как доходят

Comment: Можно сделать проверку что если секунд больше или равно чем в часе использовать `echo date('H:i:s',$time);`